How to rotate an image in a picture box properly in C#
I want to create a encoder-like user input in a c# winForms application and i used a image for the input graphics (for now a temporary image). To rotate the picture, i updated a variable called 'mouseDown' when the mouse was pressed or released over the picture box. Now when i move the mouse up or down the image should rotate indicating a theoretical rotation of an encoder. And thats how far it works. with one problem: with every rotation step it does, the image gets more and more distorted. please note that i am fairly new to C# and so far mostly worked in java!
I've searched google and found really nothing that's well documented on how to rotate an Image inside a PictureBox. Exept following question on Microsoft Forums
My full code thats handling the rotation actions:
private void Encoder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    pressedLabel.Text = "pressed";
}

private void Encoder_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int prevY = 0;
            if (e.Y > prevY)
            {
                EncoderValue.Text = (prevY - e.Y).ToString();

                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = new Bitmap(EncoderPictureBox.Image);
                rotatedBitmap.SetResolution(512, 512);

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBitmap);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(EncoderPictureBox.Image.Width / 2,             EncoderPictureBox.Image.Height / 2);
                graphics.RotateTransform((float) - 1.5);
                graphics.ScaleTransform((float) 1, (float) 1);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(-EncoderPictureBox.Image.Width / 2, -EncoderPictureBox.Image.Height / 2);
                graphics.DrawImage(rotatedBitmap, new PointF(0,0));

                EncoderPictureBox.Image = rotatedBitmap;
                prevY = e.Y;
            } else if (e.Y < prevY)
            {
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = new Bitmap(EncoderPictureBox.Image);
                rotatedBitmap.SetResolution(512, 512);

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBitmap);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(EncoderPictureBox.Image.Width / 2, EncoderPictureBox.Image.Height / 2);
                graphics.RotateTransform((float) 1.5);
                graphics.ScaleTransform((float)1, (float)1);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(-EncoderPictureBox.Image.Width / 2, -EncoderPictureBox.Image.Height / 2);
                graphics.DrawImage(rotatedBitmap, new PointF(0, 0));

                EncoderPictureBox.Image = rotatedBitmap;
                prevY = e.Y;
            } 
        }
    }
}

private void Encoder_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
    pressedLabel.Text = "notPressed";
}

And some Images as reference (before/after):



Do not reuse already rotated image for drawing the next one, always rotate the source image. And do not create the destination bitmap from existing image, use an empty one:
    bool mouseDown;
    Point mouseDownPoint;
    //Bitmap SourceImage = ...

    private void Encoder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        mouseDownPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void Encoder_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int d = e.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y;

        if (mouseDown)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = new Bitmap(SourceImage.Width, SourceImage.Height);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBitmap);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(SourceImage.Width / 2, SourceImage.Height / 2);
                graphics.RotateTransform((float)d);
                graphics.ScaleTransform((float) 1, (float) 1);
                graphics.TranslateTransform(-SourceImage.Width / 2, -SourceImage.Height / 2);
                graphics.DrawImage(SourceImage, new PointF(0,0));
                EncoderPictureBox.Image = rotatedBitmap;
            }
        }
    }


Thank you sooo much!! it works, but now the border of the button icon gets darker and darker with each rotation

Edit: the icon gets still blurred but slower and there is a border around the icon getting darker and darker with each rotation

Then the code probably differs a bit, since it works well in my test. Post it here and we'll find it.

Sorry i Interpreted the code wrong it works fine thank you!

Important side note: bitmaps are unmanaged IDisposable objects. You have to store EncoderPictureBox.Image in a variable at the start of this code, and after replacing it, check if that old image variable contains an image object, and Dispose it if it does. Otherwise you have a memory leak, since you keep making more Bitmaps but never clean them up.

Alternatively, you can just assign an image to the picture box only once, in the constructor, and on every rotation, simply create a Graphics object from that existing image, and fully clear it before painting the rotated image on it. And, either way, both the original source image and the one in the PictureBox need to be explicitly disposed in your form's Dispose(bool disposing) function.
